# Is quantum computing a serious usable instrument for the IT industry?

Tags: probability-theory, quantum-computing

Following this latest and very exciting research object I can't find till now a usable computer. By computer I understand a definitive switchable Hardware.

I would like to call actual "quantum computing" by the topic **"researching of quantum elements for computing"**. Till now I found only expensive and complex quantum circuits.

We - till now - don't have usable, steerable elements to get definitive decisions by switches. We can't find that elements in that subatomic level. We cant find - till now - definitive usable switch-instruments like relays or bistabile chips - till now. We only follow mathematical rules coming from probability formulas.

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: There is some discussion about the current state of development of useful quantum computers [in this question on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2499/253).